# Cannot boot Windows 8 install cd in uefi mode

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation, uefi

I have a Toshiba Satellite that came with windows 8 pre-installed on it. After foolishly wiping the HDD, I acquired a Windows 8 install disk.

My problem is that the computer will skip attempting to install from the disk, but ONLY while the firmware is set to UFI. While set to CSM mode, the install CD boots and will proceed with the install until it refuses to install to any partition because of something GPT related.

The disk works fine on other machines, and when booting under UFI mode my computer simply attempts to boot from the next device in boot order (the HDD).

What I want to know is, 
- why is my computer skipping my install cd? Why only when I boot in UFI?
- How can I force my computer to boot from the install cd in UFI?
- If the above is impossible, how can I force Windows 8 to install through the GPT error?

Comment: try my answer first please, you will solve your problem.

Comment: Are you attempting to install a 32bit or 64bit version of Windows 8? The 32bit disc will not boot in UEFI mode on 64bit CPUs, because WinPE requires matching architectures. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824898.aspx

Comment: Hey Robin Hood, I am using matching architectures. My install CD is 64-bit and the computer is as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "problem". The settings your laptop came with won't work because secure boot is enabled. Try to keep your "BIOS" in UEFI mode and just disable secure boot.

Comment: This makes no sense windows 8 supports secure boot there isn't any reason it shouldn't work

Comment: Not sure if it's the case for every laptop, but mine only boots from the hard drive with secure boot enabled.

Comment: secure boot has nothing to do with the boot devices detected. it is uses during Windows loading to ensure it hasn't been compromised. Maybe when you disabled it , also UEFI got disabled , and CSM went to Legacy boot (old BIOS mode).

Comment: No, disabling secure boot and going back to  legacy mode are two different settings in my UEFI. Anything that doesn't have a valid crypto signature won't show in the boot device selection screen with secure boot enabled.

Comment: secure boot is disabled. Enabling secure boot creates an error if I boot from either the hard drive or my win8 install cd

Comment: @Forrest Keppler What error do you recieve when attempting to boot with Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: Secure boot has nothing to do with USB bootable Windows install disk. If it's created on GPT (UEFI mode) , it will show as a bootable disk.

Comment: @GeorgeDima It may show, but secure boot will control whether it's allowed.

Comment: i explain it again, even if Secure BOOT it's OFF or ON, the install disk will boot , cause it's official image !

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

First of all, if I remember well, only 8.1 x64 supports UEFI.

second, you need to make a USB installation disk for UEFI: get the free tool [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), open it, select the ISO image file of your Windows version that you have downloaded, and for settings select GPT and FAT32, the others leave default.

After booting, the UEFI will see the new UEFI boot device (USB) and allow you to boot from it and install.

also, make sure you get the latest 8.1 Update 1 ISO MSDN (April-2014), this way you'll have fewer updates to do after install.

Comment: Niether 8.1, nore a usb are required for UEFI. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824898.aspx

Comment: you don't understand the problem, read more and talk after, it's about UEFI bootable Windows install disk, not about native UEFI support from Windows.

Comment: I do understand the question, and while the link does focus on installations, it does also cover media as well.

Comment: and what is your sollution other than creating an UEFI (GPT) USB install disk ?

Comment: I don't yet have a solution; I'm currently awaiting a response to the detail I requested from him about which disc he's using, 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: this answer did not work for me. I have the same problem using the usb formatted in GPT with FAT32 file system that I had using the cd:
with uefi boot mode I get a "checking media: failed" message, and with csm boot I cannot install because "the selected disk is of the gpt partition style"

Comment: strange, so you are booting on UEFI mode with Secure boot disabled,correct? when you get that error? on boot do you press the key from bootable disk selection and the USB UEFI disk appears there? what version of Windows DVD/ISO do you have?